# Basic Java: Error: Class, Interface, or Enum Expected

Tags: java

I am trying to write a method to see if the string is a palindrome (Words that can be spelled correctly backwards too, for example "racecar". I cant find the error so maybe another set of eyes will help. Here is the code:

```
public boolean isPalindrome(String str){
  numberofQuestions++;
  int n = str.length();
  for( int i = 0; i < n/2; i++ )
  if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(n-i-1)) return false;
  return true;
}
```

EDIT: Screenshot of errors:

[image]

Start of class:

```
public class Geek{
private String name;
private int numberofQuestions=0;
```

Final Edit: Found an extra "{" inside one of the methods. Thanks to everyone for your help!

Comment: I assume numberofQuestions is defined

Comment: What's the purpose of `numberofQuestions++`?! #HighlyCurious

Comment: There is no apparent error. Try looking at the stack trace and finding what piece of code has the error.

Comment: R.J, that is a counter to keep track of the number of questions used in the menu.

Comment: Show us your whole code.

Comment: A good IDE would have allowed you to format the code and avoided the question

Answer (score 9):

I bet it is something related to missing braces, or braces that closes the class body before starting this method definition.

Comment: you win the bet. perfect. Thanks

Comment: you win the bet. perfect. Thanks

Comment: I can't believe this useless answer is the accepted one after all these years.

Answer (score 2):

The method should be fully enclosed within a class

```
public class Geek {
    private String name;
    private int numberofQuestions = 0;

        public boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
            numberofQuestions++;
            int n = str.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
                if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(n - i - 1))
                    return false;
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This would fail because `numberofQuestions` is not initialized.

Comment: @Quincunx Only local variables need to be initialized. Fields have the default value if not explicitly initialized.

Comment: @Quincunx numberofQuestions will be initialized with 0 automatically because its a class variable

Comment: Beginning of class posted

Comment: @user2943817 Then please post the class so we can see it

Comment: And always use braces.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `isPalindrome()` function static.

Here's a sample:

```
public class Sample {

    private static int numberofQuestions;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String str = "racecar";
        String str2 = "notpalindrome";
        boolean test = isPalindrome(str);
        boolean test2 = isPalindrome(str2);
        System.out.println(str + ": " + test);
        System.out.println(str2 + ": " + test2);
    }

    public static boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
        numberofQuestions++;
        int n = str.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
            if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(n - i - 1))
                return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
racecar: true
notpalindrome: false
```

Answer (score 0):

You must check your curly braces that whether it is properly ended after looping , method and class.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem in curly braces. You didnt end the bracket of main class Geek{ }.

Check this:

```
  public class Geek 
   {
        private String name;
        private int numberofQuestions = 0;

            public boolean isPalindrome(String str) 
            {
                numberofQuestions++;
                int n = str.length();
                for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
                    if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(n - i - 1))
                        return false;
                return true;
            }
   }
```